# Is it best to use primitve or objects as method parameters and return values in JAVA?

Tags: java, parameters

In JAVA (and I guess in general OO languages), is it best to use primitive or objects as method parameters and return values?

When I say "primitive" or "objects", I'm talking about Long or long, int or Integer, etc.

for example :

```
public int doStuff(int number1, int number2) {
...
}

OR

public Integer doStuff(Integer number1, Integer number2) {
...
}

OR

public Integer doStuff(int number1, int number2) {
...
}

OR 

public int doStuff(Integer number1, Integer number2) {
...
}
```

I guess that we should be careful with objects as parameters since they can be null?

Comment: The answer is: it depends.

Comment: Well I think all depends what you are thinking of do with those variables.there are any particular uses you want use it?

Comment: No particular case, I just wanted a general rule when  I have the choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess that we should be careful with objects as parameters since they can be null?

Exactly. That's why I use the primitive type to express that the value can not be null, and the wrapper type to express that it can be null.

For instance:

```
/**
 * @param threads  the desired number of threads, or null if the number 
 *                 of threads should be chosen automatically.
 */
void setNumberOfThreads(Integer threads) { ... }
```

or

```
/**
 * @returns the number of children, or null if not known.
 */
Integer countChildren() { ... }
```

but:

```
void setVelocity(double dx, double dy);
```

because a null velocity would wreck havoc with the physics simulation.

Comment: you can still get NPEs. For example doing this will cause an NPE because of autoboxing:
`Double myDx=null;
Double myDy=null;
setVelocity(myDx,myDy); //will compile but NPE at runtime`

Comment: In general I don't think using null in that way is a good idea (and the win32 is a great example of the consequences it can have). Method overloading does have its problems, but it was created to solve this problem and makes the calling code much clearer.

Comment: @Nikita: Yes, but the NPE will occur in the calling method. I can not be held responsible for what my callers do :-) Moreover, the eclipse compiler will actually issue a warning in your example.

Comment: @Voo: I agree overloading can be an alternative, perhaps I chose a poor example. I'll add a (hopefully) better one :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know which you should use, you should prefer primitive type. By using primitive type, you can use `==` and you'll never get a `NullPointerException`. If you need `null` in some cases, use boxed primitives (object).

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Not every language makes this distinction, some only have objects (in the narrow sense). And I don't think the question has much to do with OO principles.

What is the difference between both?

There may be a performance difference. But you know the old saying about premature optimization? If you don't have a performance problem here then don't care for it. Your time as developer is more important than processor time.

Leaves semantic differences: In Java there is one big difference. Objects can be null. So if you need nullable values (database IDs!) use objects. Otherwise the primitive types have a nicer syntax sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on what you are doing in the client code which uses your method.My advise is to try the best to use primitives. And use reference types in a case where you cant find a way to get your job done using primitives.Following example will show you how harmful the reference types are.

```
 // Hideously slow program! Can you spot the object creation?
public static void main(String[] args) {
Long sum = 0L;
for (long i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
sum += i;
}
System.out.println(sum);
}
```

In this case it creates unwanted 2^31 Long objects. Insted of using Long type(for sum variable) and replace it with long you will gain a good performance enhancement.